# Subir carpeta al servidor mediante input type file con webkitdirectory en IE11

Tags: html, html5, internet-explorer-11

Quiero subir al servidor el contenido de una carpeta que ha de seleccionar mediante un input type file y para ello debo de especificar que quiero seleccionar carpetas y no archivos. Para ello he visto que existe una propiedad no oficial **webkitdirectory** que es compatible con Edge, Firefox y Chrome, pero que no lo es para IE11.

El caso es que el navegador que usan los usuarios de la aplicación es IE11 por lo que no puedo seguir por esta vía. He mirado temas de Drag and Drop pero igualmente veo que no son compatibles con IE11 y los ejemplos que he visto al final usan también **webkitdirectory**.

Existe alguna alternativa ??

```js
document.getElementById("filepicker").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  let output = document.getElementById("listing");
  let files = event.target.files;

  for (let i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    let item = document.createElement("li");
    item.innerHTML = files[i].webkitRelativePath;
    output.appendChild(item);
  };
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="filepicker" name="fileList" webkitdirectory multiple />
<ul id="listing"></ul>
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Lamentablemente la respuesta es que no se puede hacer tal cual quieres, es una limitación del navegador en sí y no se puede "parchear" de ninguna forma.

Lo más cercano sería que el `input` tuviera el atributo *multiple* para seleccionar varios ficheros, pero el usuario tendría que entrar carpeta por carpeta para seleccionarlos, en lugar de seleccionar una carpeta y que todo fichero en ese árbol se seleccionara

Comment: Gracias @Pablo Lozano, he visto la opción del multiple pero no es una opción viable.